# hasManyThrough not working

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have this table,

```
categories: id | name | slug
Products: id | name | slug | category_id | brand_id
Brands: id | name | slug |
```

The problem occurs when I try to bring Brands here in the category of feature.

**Category Model**

```
public function brands()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Brand', 'App\Product' 'brand_id', 'id');
}
```

The brand either does not appear or is displayed in the wrong category.

Is there any other way to get through the Brands products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your relationship as below:

```
public function brands()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Brand', 'App\Product' 'category_id','id','brand_id');
}
```

But, I doubt you can use `hasManyThrough()` to retrieve this relation. 
As given on [laravel site](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), your table should have following relation.

`Category` 1-* `Product` 1-* `Brand` 
Which is not possible in your case.

I think you have to do it manually using something like below:

```
public function Brands($category_id){
    $products = Category::find($category_id)->Products()->get()->pluck('brand_id');
    $brands = Brands::whereIn('id','=',$products)->get();
    return $brands;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is belongsToManyRelation

**Category Model**

```
    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Brands', 'products', 'category_id', 'brand_id');
    }
```